# Don't repeat values in loop

Tags: php, mysql

I've the following `query`

[image: Query]

As you see `jigsaw` repeats twice because the movie has two categories
but i would like to echo both categories but not twice the movie..

```
<?php
    while ($mInfo = $testquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">

    <a href="movie.php?title=<?php echo $mInfo['titleEN']; ?>&m=<?php echo $mInfo['imdbID']; ?>" title="<?php echo $mInfo['titleEN']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $mInfo['titleEN']; ?>" target="_self">
    <div class="movie-info">

        <img src="assets/images/poster/<?php echo $mInfo['poster']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $mInfo['titleEN']; ?>">
    </div>



    <div class="movieinformation">
        <div class="movie-title"><?php echo $mInfo['titleEN']; ?></div>
            <div class="movie-categories">I WOULD LIKE TO ECHO THE CATEGORIES HERE</div>
            </div>


            </a>

        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

So far i just could do it, could anyone help me with that?

Comment: and then I won't get all the genres that belongs to that movies...

Comment: in the loop: echo the category _always_, echo the title only if the now active title is different to the old title. At the end of the loop set old title to active title.

Comment: @jeff didn't understand what you meant... what old and new? its the SAME movie, with different categories

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`, change movieID to the first field in the select.

Comment: didnt get any effects...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concept for such tasks. I kept it with general names and left out html on purpose.

```
$oldMainId = null; // Initialize to null to start with. This will be needed later.
while ($item = $result->fetch()) { // get your items (movies in your case)
    if($oldMain != $item['mainId']) {
        // only show title if you haven't yet
        echo $item['mainTitle'];
    }
    // always show the category though
    echo $item['sub'];

    // re-set the 'old' variable. 
    $oldMainId = $item['mainId'];
}
```

Comment: tbh i cant undertsand what you meant with the 'old' title.. can you explain your thinking?

Comment: 'old' is the item you have already shown. This gives you the possibility to check if an item is 'new' (=different than the old one) and you need show it.

Comment: Thats perfect but how could i put the genres in the middle of my code?

Comment: you can have the condition (`if($oldMain != $item['mainId']) {..`) twice in your code! So it's just a question of smart restructuring...:)

Comment: the category is the `$item['sub']`

Answer (score 0):

I would use

OPTION 1

```
 $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Then it will group on the first column, assuming that is movie ID, or something unique to the movie you would get multiple rows in a nested array for that movie.

Then when you iterate thorough them you can loop over the nested array for the genre stuff

OPTION 2

Another option is to use `GROUP_CONCAT` and group by the movie id,

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(genre) AS genre, ... WHERE ... GROUP BY movieID
```

But be aware that `GROUP_CONCAT` does have a setting for max length and it will silently truncate your data if it exceeds it.

OPTION 3

You can build the structure yourself (same as fetch group does)

```
 $data = [];
 while ($mInfo = $testquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $key = $mInfo['movieid']
      if(!isset($data[$key]))  $data[$key] = [];

     $data[$key][] = $mInfo;

 }
```

Then go through that and do your html by using a second `foreach($data as ...)`  It has to be done after organizing the data as the order of the result is unknown.

Comment: But if i fetched by group it will not show all of the categories for the same movie..

Comment: if you group it by the movie, then the records for said movie will be in a nested array. you still get all the same data it's just organized by what you group it on, ie the first column.  This has nothing to do with grouping in SQL

Comment: if i do a concat then I cant add href for each category

Comment: You can do `explode` on it or, you can search and replace the commas.  For explode you may wan't to define the seperator to get rid if the `{space}` if there is one,  Personally I don't like GROUP_CONCAT